# Edit a CSV file using a batch script

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, suffix

I need to edit a column in a CSV file.

There had been a suggestion earlier on the website about using a helper batch file called `repl.bat`. This works great but my requirement is to add a suffix to the parameter name to all the parameters in that particular column.

e.g. if the input file has a parameter `abc`, then the output should be `abc_1I`.

The code which I had written using the [helper batch file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat) was:

```
type file.csv |repl "abc*" "abc*_1I"  >newfile.csv
```

The thing in this code is that even the `*_` is being shown in the CSV file.

Comment: I don't think you will finde someone downloading some batch file from some Dropbox location and _then_ help you fix your issues.

Comment: @UweKeim I understand but I have put this up for people who need a reference. If there is any other solution also, I would appreciate .

Comment: the documentation `repl /?` has a section that explains about usage of `$1` and `$[N]`